# Regex matches specific occurences

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex (PCRE2) to scrape data from mail, I am having issue trying to match specific occurrence.

Example:

```
Person Requesting

Salutation Mr.
First Name* Paul
Last Name* John

Person Handling Request

Salutation Ms.
First Name* Alice
Last Name* Parish
```

I am using the following regex to get the first name: `(?<=First Name\*).+`. So, I get `Paul`, what I want to do is having different regex to get the second matches only.

I tried using lookaround function :

```php
(?=Person Handling Request)+(?<=First Name\*).+
```

My question is, how would I go to get only the `First Name` from `Person Handling Request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?s)Person Handling Request.*?First Name\*\s*\K(?-s).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2qfRM/1). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - make `.` match line break chars, too
- `Person Handling Request` - a fixed string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `First Name\*` - a `First Name*` fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes all text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `(?-s)` - disable DOTALL effect
- `.+` - match and return the rest of the line (one or more chars other than line break chars).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for the quick reply, it's exactly what I am looking for and thanks also for the explanation it will help me in the future !

Comment: @Smoogy Then why did you say it is PCRE2? What "engine" are you using?

Comment: Sorry deleted previous comment, I wanted to edit..., I apologize for misleading I am new to regex and apparently it uses .NET,.

Comment: @Smoogy Use `(?s)(?<=Person Handling Request.*?First Name\*\s)(?-s).+`. Or, `(?s)Person Handling Request.*?First Name\*\s*(?-s)(.+)` and get Group 1.